# Showing a progressdialog in android while a large method is executed

Tags: java, android, progressdialog, oncreate

I have a long running method that is called during onCreate, this method populates textviews so interacts with the UI, and updates maybe 70 labels (about 3-20 seconds depending on device).

I want to display a progressdialog as this method executes.

Ideally I want to fire my method on the UI thread once the Activity has been displayed and the progress is displayed, this I cannot do, the Activity won't paint until the method has finished.

I hoped to find an event which was fired after  the activity was displayed, and I found the one below, but it still leaves the screen black until the method has finished.

@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

I am normally a WP7 developer, and in .NET you add an event handler for onLoadComplete which is fired after the ui is displayed, but before the user has a chance to interact withthe UI, how do I do this in Android JAVA?

Thanks

Comment: have you seen painless threathing ?

Answer (score 0):

Put a ProgressBar in the View.

Then in the onCreate() or onResume() method do this:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        yourLargeMethod();
    }
}.start();
```

Now you can do this inside your method to update the progressBar

```
public void yourLargeMethod() {
// doSomething
...

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // update the progress from the thread
            progressBar.setProgress(x); // x is your progress, 0 <= x <= progressBar.getMax()
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's probably better to use an AsyncTask.

Comment: With AsyncTask though, I would have to update the UI 70 odd times, as well as wiring up event handlers to buttons and the like. my long method is not a calculation, it is setting up a large onscreeen report, so having it run on the UI thread is most  advantagous for me, I just need to block the UI with a progress bar while it is being built. Are there no events called post render of the Activity?

Comment: Why don't you show a ProgressBar and in a separate thread build the UI in a ViewGroup of your choice that's not being displayed. At the end add the resulting ViewGroup to the main layout and remove/hide the ProgressBar. If you doit in the UI thread the progressBar will not move and the device will not respond to commands.